# Is there a way to make the MFC app work both ways console as well as Window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Is there a way to make the MFC app work both ways console as well as Window.

Comment: Not sure why this is community wiki. Certainly seems like there would be a "definitive answer" to this question...

Comment: I am not sure what you want to ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it is slightly complicated. You would call `AttachConsole()`, instead of creating any windows, when you want to run as a console app.

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be done! There are way to achieve more or less the same result though. Here's the authoritative source: [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/?p=19643) .

Answer (score 0):

depends which mfc class are you using.! you can run MFC program both Console and Windows.
However it totally depend upon what you going to program, which is not clear from your question.

I have programmed window application written in MFC to run both in Windows and console application, but that is project related requirement.